# UIAlertView is dismissed, but UIKeyboard lags

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, uialertview

I am running iOS8 and I am showing a UIAlertView, like this

```
UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" message:@"Please enter number" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Enter" otherButtonTitles:nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] becomeFirstResponder];
[alert show];
```

And then when the enter is tapped I have

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{


NSLog(@"Entered: %@",[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text]);
}
```

And when enter is tapped the method is called an I see the number and the UIAlertView goes away but the keyboard lags for about 1 second or 2. How can I make is so that the keyboard doesn't lag, I tried calling

```
[self resignFirstResponder];
```

from with in the clickedButtonAtIndex method but it didn't change anything.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "I am running iOS8 and I am showing a UIAlertView" You should update to UIAlertController.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the view controller (self) to resignFirstResponder but it's actually the text field that it the first responder, so do this:

```
[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] resignFirstResponder];
```